# Nested routes react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make sense of some nested routes. I'm not sure if I set it up correctly

I have a component called Dashboard which will hold all content but if the path is not matched it will display a 404 page. When I try to hit /about it directs me to the 404 page all the time?

[image: Edit react-router-v6 (forked)]

Comment: Why not just give all 4 routes in app.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-v6xtk

• As [Muhammed Jaseem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14555991/muhammed-jaseem) suggested — all your routes should be put in one component.

• It is also better practice to create one js/jsx component per page.

Comment: My plan was to have Dashboard contain the navigation bar and based on selected menu item it will load the necessary page. This is why it's not all in one component so within let say "/' route it will load dashboard and within dashboard I click "/about" it will load the about component within dashboard as a child

Comment: That's respectable. If your code on `Dashboard.js` further scales up you might feel the need to isolate your components

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get working but seems to direct me to a page not found. Are you able to update your example on how I should set it up? The dashboard should load any child pages and if no route is found just display not found page (outside the dashboard)

Comment: Certainly, I am on it

Comment: I think the problem stems from `<Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />` which is what is seen first by the router. Whichever isn't `/home` will redirect you to `NotFoundPage`

Comment: How would I satisfy the page not found outside the dashboard if the route does not exist? I took a non nested route at first was working just fine maybe I just over complicated it

Comment: I have updated my code, the `About` and `Contact` functions are still in `Dashboard.js` Tell me if this new approach is okay with you. Indeed, I think this is overly complicating things, if you wish to access the `About` page from the root i.e. `/About` then it should be routed in `App.js`. If you want to access it through `/Home/About` however (which isn't what you are looking for) then you may nest the routes inside `Dashboard.js`

Answer (score 0):

The routes are supposed to be defined in the app.js file.

I assume you want to serve the 'About' component when '/home/about' is hit. To achieve this you must nest the Route definitions like:

```
<Route path="/home" element={<Dashboard />}>
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />}/>
      <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
</Route>
```

Of course the 'About' and 'Contact' components need to be in their own files and imported the same way you imported the 'Dashboard' component.

Finally, the 'to' attributes of the 'Link' components in your Dashboard.js need to be changed to the full path for example '/home/about'.

Comment: an absolute path inside of nested routes is allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

use

`<Route path="/home/*" element={<Dashboard />} />`

and

`<Link to="contact" className="link">Contact</Link>`